# Changing toggle switch (4 wires) to Caseta dimmer switch (3 wires)

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am changing a toggle switch 4 wires (including ground) to Caseta Dimmer 3 wires (Including ground).  How do I attach the wires, please?
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell how the wires are connected in the picture. Did you disconnect any wires from the switch? It looks like the two black wires are connected together. Are they?

Comment: Does the new dimmer have wire leads?  How many lights does this switch control?